# How do I keep scipy's loadmat() from implicitly converting complex data types into reals while keeping the original data types?

Tags: python, scipy

Using SciPy 1.9.3 in Python 3.11.1, I am attempting to load data from a MATLAB `mat` file, which contains a couple matrices with complex doubles.  When I execute `scipi.io.loadmat(filename, matlab_compatible=True)`, I get the following warning message:

```
ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
```

And, indeed, the loaded matrices contain just the real component of the complex numbers. After trying some variations, I was finally able to get complex data loaded, with a caveat.  It seems the issue is related to the `mat_dtype=True` parameter, which is implicitly set with `matlab_compatible=True`.  If I set it to `False`, then I get complex numbers. However, it also means that various other loaded arrays in the file may be of a smaller storage class than they should be (because MATLAB will potentially use a smaller storage class to save space).

So, how do I keep the original storage class (as would be loaded in MATLAB), but also keep the complex numbers?

Comment: While I"ve used `loadmat`, I haven't played with this `matlab_compatible` option.  Since `loadmat` is largely compiled code it's hard(er) to read, much less modify.  If the parameters don't do what you want, there's not much else you can do.  But I'm puzzled about that 'lower precision' concern.  If it's **stored** with a smaller dtype, you can't "increase precision" by using another - a longer dtype may show extra nonzero digits, but that's not changing the precision.

Comment: Yeah, "precision" was the wrong term to use here.  I'll change that.  For clarity, MATLAB may save the data with the smallest storage class it can get away with (e.g. uint8 if the values are all less than 256), but still annotates the data with the original storage class (e.g. uint64).  In our case, we want the loaded data to retain the original storage class (uint64), not the serialized storage class (uint8).

Comment: With my current computer boot I csn't create a sample file with either matlab or octave.

Comment: Most of the SO `loadmat` questions have to with making sense of the complicated arrays that 'recreate' matlab cell and struct.

Comment: It turns out this is a bug in the code.  I've submitted a bugfix PR (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/17661).